# Get index of minimum value in a row combined with other constraints

Tags: python, numpy

I need to find the index of the minimum per row in a 2-dim array which at the same time satifies additional constraint on the column values. Having two arrays `a` and `b`

```
a = np.array([[1,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]])

b = np.array([[1,-1,2],[4,-1,1],[1,-1,2],[1,2,-1]])
```

the objective is to find the indicies for which holds that `a == 1`, `b` is positive and `b` is the minimumim value of the row. Fulfilling the first two conditions is easy

```
idx = np.where(np.logical_and(a == 1, b > 0))
```

which yields the indices:

```
(array([0, 0, 1, 3, 3]), array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1]))
```

Now I need to filter the duplicate row entries (stick with minimum value only) but I cannot think of an elegant way to achieve that. In the above example the result should be

```
(array([0,1,3]), array([0,2,0]))
```

**edit**:

It should also work for `a` containing other values than just `0` and `1`.

Comment: Could you [edit] to include what your desired output is?

Comment: @JonClements I added the expected output.

Comment: Might be me but I don't understand why `0` occurs twice and `1` is dropped in the example output?

Comment: Use the condition on `a` and you get indices in two dimensions. Check at those places in `b` if it coincides with the smallest (per row) non-negative value. If not, drop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to trying to understand the problem better, try:

```
c = b*(b*a > 0)
np.where(c==np.min(c[np.nonzero(c)]))
```

Output:

```
(array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64), array([0, 2, 0], dtype=int64))
```

### Timings:

*Method 1*

```
a = np.array([[1,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]])
b = np.array([[1,-1,2],[4,-1,1],[1,-1,2],[1,2,-1]])
b[b<0] = 100000
cond = [[True if i == b.argmin(axis=1)[k] else False for i in range(b.shape[1])] for k in range(b.shape[0])]
idx = np.where(np.logical_and(np.logical_and(a == 1, b > 0),cond))
idx
```

*Method 2*

```
c = b*(b*a > 0)
idx1 = np.where(c==np.min(c[np.nonzero(c)]))
idx1
```

Method 1 Timing:

> 28.3 µs ± 418 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

Method 2 Timing:

> 12.2 µs ± 144 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand how this is related to my problem.

Comment: One drawback of method 2 is that it throws an exception when the argument of min() is an emtpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on list comprehension. It is necessary to change the negative values of b to some high value though.

```
a = np.array([[1,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]])
b = np.array([[1,-1,2],[4,-1,1],[1,-1,2],[1,2,-1]])
b[b<0] = 100000
cond = [[True if i == b.argmin(axis=1)[k] else False for i in range(b.shape[1])] for k in range(b.shape[0])]
idx = np.where(np.logical_and(np.logical_and(a == 1, b > 0),cond))
print(idx)

(array([0, 1, 3]), array([0, 2, 0]))
```

Please let me hear what you think.

**edit**: I just noticed that this solution is horribly slow.